# Installing a full linux OS on a usb drive without iso image, rather from a CD/DVD!

Tags: system-installation, usb

I was wandering if that's even possible! The other day my hdd crashed and it got me into thinking what if I could install a full OS on a usb(not live os though) from my cd/dvd that I had. So i fired up my pc without a hdd and with a kali-i386 cd along with my 4gb usb drive. Sadly the installation halted at the installation step which I assume is because of the 4gb size(it's not enough ig). Apparently I dont have any plans on buying a new usb drive for now. So..is that possible!!! And have anyone actually tried it though!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: It is possible, but 4GB is not enough. If that is a requirement, Ubuntu and derivatives are not for you.

Comment: Have a look at Puppy Linux, It will fit on 4GB with room to spare. There are Ubuntu compatible versions: http://puppylinux.com/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should really get a larger size USB drive for what you are trying to do. I recommend something above 32gb, as 16gb wouldn't be enough.
2) To answer your question, as far as i know, the installer should use the flash drive as long as the internal drive is disconnected from the computer.

Comment: yep!! thanks for the size reccommendations and I'm well aware of point no.2 thank you c:

Comment: Using the 'something else' option on the installer DVD, you can specify where to install, HD external or internal, USB or SD card if you want.  You still need a drive that can hold it.